# IPsec isakmp_natt problem on racoon.conf

Tags: vpn, freebsd, ipsec, racoon

I have this weird problem where racoon complains of the following error:

```
WARNING: NAT-T is enabled in at least one remote{} section, but no 'isakmp_natt' address was specified!
```

I've already specified isakmp_natt though.  Here's my racoon.conf:

```
path pre_shared_key "/var/etc/psk.txt";

path certificate  "/var/etc";

listen
{
    isakmp 172.17.69.69 [500];
    isakmp_natt 172.17.69.69 [4500];
}


mode_cfg
{
    auth_source system;
    group_source system;
    pool_size 125;
    network4 172.19.3.1;
    netmask4 255.255.255.128;
}


remote 172.17.43.43
{
    ph1id 1;
    exchange_mode aggressive;
    my_identifier address 172.17.69.69;
    peers_identifier address 172.17.43.43;
    ike_frag on;
    generate_policy = off;
    initial_contact = on;
    nat_traversal on;

    dpd_delay = 10;
    dpd_maxfail = 5;
    support_proxy on;
    proposal_check claim;

    proposal
    {
        authentication_method pre_shared_key;
        encryption_algorithm 3des;
        hash_algorithm sha1;
        dh_group 2;
        lifetime time 28800 secs;
    }
}

sainfo subnet 192.168.168.0/24 any subnet 10.234.34.0/24 any
{
    remoteid 1;
    encryption_algorithm aes 256, aes 192, aes 128, blowfish 256, blowfish 248, blowfish 240, blowfish 232, blowfish 224, blowfish 216, blowfish 208, blowfish 200, blowfish 192, blowfish 184, blowfish 176, blowfish 168, blowfish 160, blowfish 152, blowfish 144, blowfish 136, blowfish 128, 3des, cast128;
    authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1,hmac_md5;
    compression_algorithm deflate;

    lifetime time 3600 secs;
}
```

Thanks!

[ simon.cpu ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to recompile your kernel, with `options IPSEC_NAT_T` set in the kernel config.

Comment: Yepp, I think that was how we solved our problem... Thanks!